# TYPO3 scheduler task with Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

When creating a scheduler task with Extbase CommandController, how can I tell the scheduler extension that a task failed?
When creating tasks with scheduler (without Extbase), this is done with "return false", but this has no effect in tasks with Extbase CommandController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw an Exception. That will mark the scheduler task as failed.

Comment: One might add the following comment to Daniels answer:

Basicly if a CommandController::command finishes its marked completed, if it fails during execution it'll be marked incomplete, and if an exception is thrown the exception message will be added to the task:info. Not really any reason to add anything else, and no special config for it.